# Spring security - reading values from controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have researched the web quite a bit, but still cant find solution to my problem. Everywhere people using stuff that does not fit my case. My scenerio:

user sends with post {email:"admin", password:"admin"} then there is Login controller which checks if input is correct and after that token is returned in header/body.

Im stuck with the part where I pass the values from controller to Spring authentication process.

Below is my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    private TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;


    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.tokenAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

here is my controller :

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody LoginCredentials payload){

        Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        payload.getUsername(),
                        payload.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
    }
}
```

and this is my authentication provider

```
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        if(authentication.getName().equals("admin")  && authentication.getCredentials().equals("admin")) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials(), grantedAuths);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```

Im doing post request with credentials and this is the answer Im getting:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1486995388844,
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "exception": "org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException",
  "message": "Access Denied",
  "path": "/login"
}
```

Comment: Instead of hacking around Spring Security use the framework as it is intended to. Create a filter to do the authentication, don't try to bolt it on with a controller and hope that Spring Security does what it needs to do.

Comment: @M.Deinum. Exactly. you need to process the incoming credentials in a filter, create an Unauthenticated Authentication, which is then processed by the AuthenticationManager which resolves the roles and creates an authorized Authentication and returns a token. On subsequent requests the token is resolved against your TokenStore (db) inside another filter, and you create an authorized Authentication (if the token is valid) and set `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication` (Like Spring security does in BasicAuthenticationFilter).

Comment: ok So I need 2 filters, one checks if input from login (username,password) is correct and if so gives out valid token (which may be stored in db or just JWT), and then I have to write another filter which validates requests with attached token in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is interesting that you have chosen to create a new controller to deal with the login, but essentially you are duplicating the work that Spring Security does for you. Think about it for a second: you send a HTTP POST request to your custom controller (at a certain endpoint) which will check the credentials for the user to be authenticated by invoking the authentication provider - this is already the mechanism by which Spring Security module works (you need to perform a POST to a certain endpoint and the security container will invoke the defined authentication providers and decide if the user should be granted access or not).

I believe you do not need that controller: you just need some extra configuration to your security container, so let's begin!

BTW: Even if Spring configuration is mostly written in Java, Spring Security configuration doesn’t yet support full Java and still needs to be XML for the most part.

You can configure Spring Security to initialize the authentication process when a certain endpoint is hit (with that HTTP POST request). In XML, this is done as follows:

```
<http>
    <form-login login-processing-url="/perform_login"/>

    ...(other configuration)
</http>
```

Although I have tried to find it in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form), I can't find the equivalent Java config. We can invoke the `formLogin()` method on the `HttpSecurity` object like this:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll();
 }
```

but there seems to be no Java method to configure the login processing URL. The `loginPage()` method simply specifies the URL to send users to if login is required (that's not what we are looking for).

If you do not configure the login processing URL, the security container will just use the default one which is `/j_spring_security_check`.

So now we can POST our authentication credentials to `/perform_login`, and Spring Security will use those against its authentication filters to grant you access (or not).

Are we done? Not yet.
The default `username` and `password` parameters are called `j_username` and `j_password`, so you will have to POST these to `/perform_login` to get the desired behaviour. Luckily, we can configure the name of these two (in XML again - sorry):

```
<http>
    <form-login login-processing-url="/perform_login"/>
                username-parameter="email"
                password-parameter="password"

    ...(other configuration)
</http>
```

Now we are set! By issuing a HTTP POST with two parameters (or more if you want the CSRF tokens) - namely *email* and *password* to */perform_login*, we can authenticate properly (and we didn't have to create yet another class called `LoginCredentials` like you did.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I dont want to redirect to custom login page or anything like that. I expect user to login using given endpoint, if the creds are ok then he gets token for further request , if not he gets 401.

Comment: I am afraid I do not follow: simply set the login-processing-url as your desired endpoint, and POST your details there (the email parameter and the password parameter).

Comment: I believe you've misunderstood the effect that the login-processing-url tag has: it does not redirect you to that page, but it specifies that a POST request to that page will initialize the authentication process.

Comment: hmm I guess thats not exactly what Im looking for but thanks for answers